# Loading LayoutPanel content dynamically in Wpf

Tags: wpf, navigation, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm working on a desktop application. It has a `dropdown menu`. When a menu item is clicked on the `dropdown` a new `tab` is opened if it's not opened before. There is a single `tab` for a single `dropdown menu item`. What i want to do is to open a `window`, `page` or `user control`(i'm not sure which i should use) in seperate `tab`s considering the work they will do.

My partial `XAML`:

```
<dxd:DockLayoutManager DockItemClosing="DockLayoutManager_DockItemClosing_1">
    <dxd:LayoutGroup>
        <dxd:TabbedGroup Name="tabbedGroup">                        
        </dxd:TabbedGroup>
    </dxd:LayoutGroup>
</dxd:DockLayoutManager>
```

and partial `CS`:

```
private void addPanel(string caption)
{
    var contains = false;
    var layoutPanel = new LayoutPanel() { Caption = caption };

    BaseLayoutItem[] baseLayoutItem = tabbedGroup.GetItems();

    foreach (var layoutItem in baseLayoutItem)
    {
        if (layoutItem.Caption.Equals(layoutPanel.Caption))
        {
            contains = true;
        }
    }

    if (!contains)
    {
        tabbedGroup.Add(layoutPanel);
    }
}
```

As i mentioned i want to append a `window`, `page` or `user control`(i'm not sure which i should use) into every `LayouPanel` opened seperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's as easy as:

```
layoutPanel.Content = new UserControl1();
```

And i got one more trick for dynamically creating the desired tab:

```
layoutPanel.Content = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(Constants.s_tabs[caption]));
```

I hope it won't cause any performance problems.

Comment: What is the downside of this solution?